# Как подключить и использовать Яндекс.Метрику в Angular приложении?

Tags: angular, yandex-metrika-api

Есть приложение на Ангуляре. Раньше использовали для метрики библиотеку для Ангуляр ng-yandex-metrika. Сейчас хотим от нее отказываться и работать напрямую через Яндекс.Метрику, отсюда появляются вопросы
Где нужно создавать и инициализировать счетчик? В документации к Метрике написано, что это нужно выполнить на каждой html-странице, но может для SPA достаточно только в index.html?
Дальше пишут про использование метода ym(), но как его использовать и где прописывать вообще непонятно. Были мысли, что может его надо как-то импортировать, но в инструкциях яндекса ничего об этом не сказано, а код выдает ошибки, что не знает что это за метод

Может здесь есть те, кто разбирается в этом и может подсказать

Comment: Посмотрите исходники ng-yandex-metrika. В общем ничего сложного, но есть нюансы для spa

Comment: Обновил библиотеку, по мне лучше сделать по ее примеру, с инициализацией через модуль. В целом Александр прав, там ничего сложного.